# How does routing work here in this application where its a mix of mvc and webforms?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

I've created an application that mixes mvc and web forms. 
I have a question about how the routing is working when I mix these two.

This is just for testing purpose only.

I have a controller called Family and it has an action method called Index.

At the same time I have a folder called family which contains an aspx page called Index.

[image]

When I go to localhost/family/Index I get the controller action method view
and when I go to localhost/family/Index.aspx I get the webform page.

How does this work?  How does it know whether to look for Family controller or Family the folder?

Answer (score 2):

When you call `localhost/family/Index` IIS looking for the route in `route config table` that defined from `RouteConfig.cs` in `App_Start` and then you can see the `Index ActionResult` from `FamilyController` but when you looking for `localhost/family/Index.aspx` IIS looking for a file that name is `Index.aspx` in the `family` folder.(of course at the first, IIS looking in route config then looking for file and folders.)